# Changing online git repository url in IntelliJ project

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

How can I change online git repository in my IntelliJ project? Project is synchronized with current repository and I push / pull changes from IDE level.

Comment: Without trying, did you try to change the URL on the command line? I doubt intellij saves it somewhere

Comment: If you do not like the command line you can edit the `.git/config` file by hand and change the url

Answer (score 14):

Within IntelliJ go to:

***Tools > Terminal Window***

And there type:

```
git remote set-url origin URLHERE
```

replacing `URLHERE` with your project git or https address.

Answer (score 8):

Within IntelliJ go to:

**VCS > Git > Remotes ...**

This will open a dialog box where you can update the origin URL for your online repository.

Comment: It just update the url only. For pushurl, the easiest way is changing in .git/config